# Como Junto los " Nombres" y "Propiedad a su Cargo "

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  E.NUMRUT_EMP ||'-'||E.DVRUT_EMP as RUT_EMPLEADO, E.NOMBRE_EMP ||' '|| E.APPATERNO_EMP as NOMBRE , COUNT(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD)"PROPIEDAD A SU CARGO" , 
CASE 
WHEN  COUNT(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD) = 4 THEN count(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD)*(P.VALOR_ARRIENDO+P.VALOR_GASTO_COMUN)
WHEN  COUNT(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD) = 3 THEN count(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD)*(P.VALOR_ARRIENDO+P.VALOR_GASTO_COMUN)
WHEN  COUNT(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD) = 2 THEN count(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD)*(P.VALOR_ARRIENDO+P.VALOR_GASTO_COMUN)
WHEN  COUNT(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD) = 1 THEN count(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD)*(P.VALOR_ARRIENDO+P.VALOR_GASTO_COMUN)
ELSE  COUNT(P.NRO_PROPIEDAD) END "COMISION"
FROM EMPLEADO E
JOIN PROPIEDADES P
ON (E.NUMRUT_EMP = P.NUMRUT_EMP)
GROUP BY E.NUMRUT_EMP, E.DVRUT_EMP, E.NOMBRE_EMP , E.APPATERNO_EMP ,P.VALOR_ARRIENDO,P.VALOR_GASTO_COMUN
ORDER BY APPATERNO_EMP
```

[image]

Como pueden ver , me salen por separado (nombre y propiedad) y necesito juntar y agruparlos , evitando que se separen

Comment: Sólo tienes que poner esto en el GROUP BY: `GROUP BY E.NUMRUT_EMP, P.NRO_PROPIEDAD`

Comment: Hola , acabo de ejecutar y no me sirvió.Gracias por la ayuda